# installing apache2, php5, mysql, phpmyadmin

Tags: apache2, mysql, php, phpmyadmin

I used the following commands

```
sudo atp-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
sudo apt-get install php5
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin

sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

after everything was done, I typed `http://localhost` in chromium... nothing happened. Can anyone help?

Comment: Please include apache error log `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: Run "service apache2 status" and "netstat -nap | grep :80" or "lsof -i :80", see if the service is up and running, also if port 80 is being used, if so, what process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed apache and all the rest reading this http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-apache2-with-php5-and-mysql-support-on-ubuntu-11.04-lamp article...
Now I want to install PDO :S Help?

Answer (score 2):

You must first check error in the apache error log. 
To check error type following command in your terminal:

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

It will show you what is the error, and resolve it accordingly, i guess you might have not configured lamp properly.

Check [here](http://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu_lamp_for_newbies) for the complete installation tutorial.

Thanks.

Comment: for installing pdo, this will help you: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php
http://wiki.kryn.org/How_to_install_php_pdo_debian/ubuntu